# Erro PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Tenho o seguinte codigo, eu utilizei um outro parecido para fazer um update da base de dados, mas esse agora não funciona; ele da o seguinte erro:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\F1\php_programmes\modificateurpilote.php on line 17

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tc4','root','');
$dbh->query('SET NAMES utf8');
$prendre = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE pilotes SET Nom=:mNom, Nationalite= :mNationalite,DateDeNaissance= :mDateDeNaissance, Annees= :mAnnees, Equipe= :mEquipe, NombreDeGP= :mNombreDeGP, Podiums= :mPodiums, Victoires= :mVictoires, TitresPilote= :TitresPilote, Description= :mDescription WHERE Id='.$_POST['id']);
$prendre->execute(array('mNom'=> $_POST['Nom'],
    'mNationalite'=> $_POST['Nationalite'],
    'mDateDeNaissance'=> $_POST['DateDeNaissance'],
    'mAnnees'=> $_POST['Annees'],
    'mEquipe'=> $_POST['Equipe'],
    'mNombreDeGP'=> $_POST['NombreDeGP'],
    'mPodiums'=> $_POST['Podiums'],
    'mVictoires'=> $_POST['Victoires'],
    'mTitresPilote'=> $_POST['TitresPilote'],
    'mDescription'=> $_POST['Description']
    )
);
```

?>

Comment: O que tem na linha 17 do arquivo `modificateurpilote.php`?

Comment: A linha 17, era o fim da funcao ja...

Comment: opaaaa, amigo, encontrei a solucao, logo abaixo

Comment: Opa, eu vi. Bacana. :D

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o erro, tratava-se que eu esqueci de colocar a variável de modificação o `m` ali pra diferenciar, em:

```
TitresPilote= :TitresPilote
```

Que no caso deveria ser:

```
TitresPilote= :mTitresPilote
```

Então ocorria o erro, porque não tinha esse parâmetro definido.